# Drift stream not updating on insert, update and delete

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-moor, drift

I'm having problem when trying to display data on the UI where it should rebuild the widget prior to changes on `menus` table. I'm using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for the state management and [Drift, a.k.a Moor](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/) as the database.

My presentation logic looks like this

`categories_panel.dart`

```dart
class CategoriesPanel extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesPanel({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const [
          // unrelated codes ommitted...

          _GridView(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GridView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const _GridView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Obx(
        () => GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          childAspectRatio: 0.8,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          children: controller.categories.map((e) {
            return CategoryCard(
              color: e.category.labelColor,
              name: e.category.name,
              itemCount: e.menus.length, // This should be updated prior to changes on menus table
              onTap: () => controller.selectedCategory(e),
              onLongPress: () => controller.showCategoryActionDialog(e),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In `HomeController`, I declared a variable named `categories` and binded the stream in `onInit` lifecycle.

`home_controller.dart`

```dart
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  HomeController({
    required CategoryRepository categoryRepository,
    required MenuRepository menuRepository,
  })  : _categoryRepository = categoryRepository,
        _menuRepository = menuRepository;

  final CategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
  final MenuRepository _menuRepository;
  final categories = <CategoryWithMenus>[].obs; // HERE

  // unrelated codes ommitted...

  @override
  void onInit() {
    categories.bindStream(_categoryRepository.stream()); // BINDED HERE
    super.onInit();
  }

  // another unrelated codes ommitted...
}
```

The stream itself, looks like this... I've tried to `listen` to the `menusStream` to print each changes to make sure it was triggerred, but it doesn't.

`category_repository.dart`

```dart
class CategoryRepository extends Database {
  Stream<List<CategoryWithMenus>> stream() {
    final categoriesQuery = select(categories);

    return categoriesQuery.watch().switchMap((categories) {
      final idToCategory = {for (var c in categories) c.id: c};
      final ids = idToCategory.keys;

      final menusStream =
          (select(menus)..where((tbl) => tbl.categoryId.isIn(ids))).watch();

      menusStream.listen(print); // This does not print anything on create, update or delete

      return menusStream.map((menus) {
        final idToMenus = <int, List<Menu>>{};

        for (final menu in menus) {
          idToMenus.putIfAbsent(menu.categoryId, () => []).add(menu);
        }

        return [
          for (var id in ids)
            CategoryWithMenus(
              category: idToCategory[id]!,
              menus: idToMenus[id] ?? [],
            ),
        ];
      });
    });
  }

  // unrelated codes ommitted...
}
```

Finally, my model, migrations and database config looks like this

`models/category_with_menus.dart`

```dart
class CategoryWithMenus {
  const CategoryWithMenus({
    required this.category,
    this.menus = const <Menu>[],
  });

  final Category category;
  final List<Menu> menus;
}
```

`database/migrations/categories.dart`

```dart
@DataClassName('Category')
class Categories extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get name => text().withLength(max: 100)();
  IntColumn get labelColor => integer().nullable()();
}
```

`database/migrations/menus.dart`

```dart
class Menus extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get name => text().withLength(max: 255)();
  RealColumn get price => real().withDefault(const Constant(0.0))();
  IntColumn get categoryId =>
      integer().references(Categories, #id, onDelete: KeyAction.cascade)();
}
```

`database/database.dart`

```dart
@DriftDatabase(tables: [
  Categories,
  Menus,
  // unrelated codes ommitted...
])
class Database extends _$Database {
  Database() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;

  @override
  MigrationStrategy get migration {
    return MigrationStrategy(
      beforeOpen: (OpeningDetails details) async {
        await customStatement('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON');
      },
    );
  }
}

LazyDatabase _openConnection() {
  return LazyDatabase(() async {
    final databaseFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File(p.join(databaseFolder.path, 'myapp.sqlite'));
    return NativeDatabase(file);
  });
}
```

I've tried to change my stream logic too but it still not working.

```dart
Stream<List<CategoryWithMenus>> stream() {
  final categoriesStream = select(categories).watch();
  final menusStream = select(menus).watch();

  return Rx.combineLatest2(
    categoriesStream,
    menusStream,
    (List<Category> a, List<Menu> b) {
      return a.map((category) {
        return CategoryWithMenus(
          category: category,
          menus: b.where((m) => m.categoryId == category.id).toList(),
        );
      }).toList();
    },
  );
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this behavior occurs after I do an extraction of the database logic into the repositories, the problem is not on the stream logic.

When I did that, I put each repositories into the bindings of `HomeBinding`

`home_binding.dart`

```dart
class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.put(CategoryRepository());
    Get.put(MenuRepository());
    Get.put(AdditionRepository());

    Get.put<AdditionFormController>(
      AdditionFormController(
        additionRepository: Get.find(),
      ),
    );

    Get.put<MenuFormController>(
      MenuFormController(
        menuRepository: Get.find(),
        additionRepository: Get.find(),
      ),
    );

    Get.put<AddMenuDialogController>(
      AddMenuDialogController(
        menuRepository: Get.find(),
      ),
    );

    Get.put<CategoryFormController>(
      CategoryFormController(
        categoryRepository: Get.find(),
      ),
    );

    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(
      () => HomeController(
        categoryRepository: Get.find(),
        menuRepository: Get.find(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Those `put` statements I think, creates new database instances for each repository so the watchers are unable to figure out that some data has been changed.

I fixed this by reverting my refactor commit and re-implementing my stream logic the exact same way as I did on my question. But now, I put all my database logic inside of `database/database.dart` instead of making a repository.

It works perfectly.